# Proxy authentication bug on Wp 8.1 GDR1

Tags: 8.1-update-1

I have a Lumia 925 with Dev Preview enabled and updated to GDR1.
In my workplace we use authenticated proxy to connect to the internet through wi-fi.
I set up the proxy server and the port on the connection advanced settings menu and I'm asked
the username and the password on Internet Explorer, but after entering username/pw I just get asked again and again...
I tested other phones (Android phones, iPhones and other Lumias) and all worked flawlessly, even my old Lumia 800 works with no problem.

I contacted our sysadmin, and he said he is able to see my phone making requests to the proxy server, but the requests have no info on password and username..

I guess this is a bug, since I'm using dev preview..

Anyone had a similar experience?

Comment: Do you know what type of authentication your proxy uses?

Comment: If you don't reply back with more details, we cannot help you or report it to Microsoft as a bug.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. Before updating my Lumia 620 to WP 8.1 I was able to get in my workplace wi-fi network.